# Cast object to KeyValuePair with "generic value"?

Tags: c#, casting, keyvaluepair

I have a ComboBox filled with mixed items of two different types. The types are either

```
KeyValuePair<Int32, FontFamily>
```

or

```
KeyValuePair<Int32, String>
```

Now there are occasions where I am only interested in the Key of the selected item, which is always an Int32.

What would be the easiest way to access the Key of the selcted item? I am thinking of something like

```
Int32 key = ((KeyValuepair<Int32, object/T/var/IdontCare>)combobox.SelectedItem).Key;
```

but that doesn´t work.

So all I have is

```
    Int32 key;
    if(combobox.SelectedItem.GetType().Equals(typeof(KeyValuePair<Int32, FontFamily)))
    {
        key = ((KeyValuePair<Int32, FontFamily)combobox.SelectedItem).Key;
    }
    else if(combobox.SelectedItem.GetType().Equals(typeof(KeyValuePair<Int32, String)))
    {
        key = ((KeyValuePair<Int32, String)combobox.SelectedItem).Key;
    }
```

which works, but I wonder if there is a more elegant way?

Comment: use object like  ``KeyValuePair<Int32, Object>``

Comment: You could use dynamic: `(int)((dyamic)selectedItem).Key)`

Comment: Ehsan: Tried before, causes InvalidCastException.

Comment: Lee: worked, thanks! (see accepted answer))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Casting to `dynamic` (poor man's reflection) can do the trick

```
var key = (int) ((dynamic) comboxbox.SelectedItem).Key);
```

Comment: That´s what Lee suggested in the comments, but I get a compiler error (CS0656) saying that member "Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create" is missing.

Comment: Include the `Microsoft.CSharp` assembly in your project.

Comment: Patrick: thanks, now it really works. Richard: Looks a little fragile, but it´s just what I was looking for. To be honest, I never used dynamic before. Will have to read about it.

Answer (score 3):

You certainly don't need to use `GetType()`. You could use:

```
int key;
var item = combobox.SelectedItem;
if (item is KeyValuePair<int, FontFamily>)
{
    key = ((KeyValuePair<int, FontFamily>) item).Key;
}
else if (item is KeyValuePair<int, string>)
{
    key = ((KeyValuePair<int, string>) item).Key;
}
```

I don't think there's really a better way without using reflection or dynamic typing, assuming you can't change the type of the selected items to your own equivalent to `KeyValuePair` with some non-generic base type or interface.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it's bound in WPF, in that case I would suggest to not use `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` but instead an own VM class. E.g.

```
class MyComboItem
{
    private String _stringValue;
    private FontFamiliy _fontFamilyValue;

    public Int32 Key {get;set;}
    public object Value => (_fontFamilyValue!=null)?_fontFamilyValue:_stringValue;
}
```

or you could have an interface like

```
interface IMyComboItem
{
    Int32 Key {get;}
    object Value {get;}
}
```

and implement two VM classes that implement it storing the proper value type.
With proper constructors and so on. Casting as you want achieve isn't possible with generics, and your solution case isn't elegant.

Comment: That really looks elegant, but since I get the KeyValuePairs from outside the class and later will give away KeyValuePairs, I would try to avoid casting.

Comment: Not casting but mapping, eventually your ComboItem VM class can be only a wrapper around the KeyValuePair class handling it properly

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own class hierarchy like this

```
public interface IComboBoxItem
{
    public int Key { get; }
}

public class ComboBoxItem<T> : IComboBoxItem
{
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public int Key { get; set; }
}
```

and your cast will look like this:

```
key = ((IComboBoxItem)combobox.SelectedItem).Key;
```

Comment: That really looks elegant, but since I get the KeyValuePairs from outside the class and later will give away KeyValuePairs, I would try to avoid casting.

Answer (score -1):

Building on Rich's answer, I used Dynamic successfully. I knew the dictionary type I was binding to (and realistically could have used the dictionary itself, since that was still referenced in my form), but I wanted to create a method to search by the displayname. This will eventually check if the binding source is a datatable too, but for now, this worked well for a <string,?> dictionary.

```
private void SetComboBoxSelection(ComboBox cmb, string ItemText)
        {
            if (cmb.DisplayMember.ToLower() == "key" && cmb.ValueMember.ToLower() == "value")
            {
                foreach (dynamic item in cmb.Items)
                    if (item.Key == ItemText)
                        cmb.SelectedItem = item.Value;
            }
        }
```